# Python: How do I find the number of occurrences of the responses of 1 variable in regards to another?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have the variables Marital Status and Race already. But how do I get the number of each category of Marital Status based on Race?

I want to know the count of White people that are married/divorced/single, and of African Americans/Asians etc.

Thank you!

Comment: Please share a sample of input dataframe with expected output.

Comment: you can add the output of `df.to_dict()` or `df.sample(n=20).to_dict()` so we can see your data

Answer (score 0):

It would help a lot if you could include an example of your data, and an example of the end result you are looking for.

It sounds like you could use `.groupby()` in combination with `.count()` for this problem:

```
df.groupby(['Race', 'Marital Status']).count()
```

Documentation on groupby:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html